# horzcat error with surface fitting Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have two column vectors and a matrix with consistent dimensions: size(x(:) = 3001 x 1, size(y(:)) = 28 x 1, size(z) = 3001 x 28.

I'm trying to do a surface fit with the line:

```
sf = fit([x, y] , z, 'linearinterp');
```

and get the horzcat error (Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent). Of course x and y have a different number of rows, but I don't wish to concatenate them. I believe I have used the correct syntax for surface fitting in matlab R2015a. I have successfully fitted the surface using the toolbox.

Comment: doing so creates a 28 x 3001 matrix. Shouldn't I pass the fit function two column vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need a `meshgrid`. You need the same amount of `x` and `y` as you have of `z`.

if they are regularly spaced (I assume, else you are missing information), then `meshgrid` will solve it as:

```
[xmesh, ymesh]=meshgrid(x,y)
sf =  fit([xmeshx(:), ymesh(:)] , z(:), 'linearinterp');
```

Comment: This didn't lead to any errors but it did not lead to the correct fit. The workaround is to save the fit from the toolbox. Does fit require z to be a square matrix for surfaces?

Comment: `fit` requires a set of points `p=[x,y,z]` to fit to. Meaning, it needs that each value of `z` has an `x` and an `y`